# RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded, animated expandable widget

Tags: flutter, dart

The following widget `expanded_title` is the title of a container that expands to the right. That is, it's a `Row` of 2 columns, but the second column only appears when expanded. Also, the expansion is animated, so I cannot give `expanded_title` a non expanded with and an expanded width.

```
      Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, 
          children: [
          Expanded(child: Container(
            child: Text(this.title),
          )),
          Expanded(child: Container(
              child: expanded
                  ? Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
                      color: CustomColors.stompaiArrow)
                  : Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                      color: CustomColors.stompaiArrow))),
          ]),
```

It should be something like this:

```
 Title   >
|Column 1 |
```

Then you click to expand, then it should expand according to its parent width to be this:

```
 Title               >
|Column 1 | |Column 2 |
```

However it's being always rendered as `Title >`, it refuses to expand to the maximum width possible. Currently I get this error:

```
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.
```

Because of the `Expanded` things inside a Container with no `width`. See below:

```
     Container(
        child: Column(children: [
          expandable_title,
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
             child: Row(
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: ExpandableColumn.COLUMN_WIDTH,
                    child: widget.child,
                  ),
                  SizeTransition(
                      sizeFactor: _animation,
                      axis: Axis.horizontal,
                      axisAlignment: -1,
                      child: Container(
                          width: ExpandableColumn.COLUMN_WIDTH,
                          child: widget.expandedChild))
                ]),
          ))
        ]))
```

As you can see, `expandable_title` is inside a `Row` that can grow, depending on the `SizeTransition` animation. So I can never.

Comment: How are you handling the boolean variabler `expanded` state? `setState` or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the code below or you could directly run the code on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/6e6d4c7a29c4e66b5d02335d1ab27007)
https://dartpad.dev/6e6d4c7a29c4e66b5d02335d1ab27007 Note: I have made up some values for variables I did not know, so if they are incorrect tell me what to change.

[image]

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
final Color darkBlue = const Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Flutter Demo"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: ListView(
                  //shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: [
                    MyWidget(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        child: const Text("Child"),
                      ),
                      expandedChild: Container(
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        child: const Text("Expanded Child"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Widget expandedChild;

  const MyWidget({Key key, this.expandedChild, this.child}) : super(key: key);
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool expanded = false;
  bool expIcon = false;
  Widget expandableTitle;

  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    expandableTitle = Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          flex: 0,
          child: Container(
            child: const Text("Flutter Animation Demo"),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 1,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() => expanded = !expanded);
              _controller.status == AnimationStatus.completed
                  ? _controller.reverse()
                  : _controller.forward();
            },
            child: Container(
              child: AnimatedAlign(
                onEnd: () => setState(() => expIcon = !expIcon),
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
                alignment:
                    expanded ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: expIcon
                    ? const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
                        color: Colors.white)
                    : const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          expandableTitle,
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints) {
                  return Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: constraints.maxWidth / 2,
                        child: widget.child,
                      ),
                      SizeTransition(
                        sizeFactor: _animation,
                        axis: Axis.horizontal,
                        axisAlignment: -1,
                        child: Container(
                          width: constraints.maxWidth / 2,
                          child: widget.expandedChild,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but my intent was for the title to expand together with the expandable column. That is, `This is big big big title >` when not expanded, and then `This is big big big title                                   <`  when expanded

Comment: I mean `This is big big big title                           (lots of spaces)            <`

Comment: Does it mean one space between This is big big big title and > when not expanded, And lots of spaces when expanded like this >>> 'This is big big big title {LOTSOFSPACES}                        <' ?

Comment: Please see the code now. I've also updated the screen recording for your reference.

Comment: Please check out the code now. I've even animated the icon transition.

Comment: I still got the error with your example. Could you kindly tell me why I still get the error in this case: https://pastebin.com/v4ESFiTV? I used your `MyWidget`, just inserted in a different structure.

Comment: Looks like the main issue is putting `MyWidget` inside a `ListView`. Since `MyWidget` uses `Expanded`, it cannot know how much it can expand to the right.

Comment: All you needed to do is give the first Container in MyWIdget the appropriate width it would use. I've updated the code and at the moment I've given the screen width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width. But you can give any width or make width a property of MyWidget. I think all issues within the scope of this question have been resolved?

Comment: I think something is not good. For example, if you add 2 MyWidget, like this: https://pastebin.com/jFEcyjhP then you end up with them unncessairly covering the whole screen instead of only the space needed when not expanded. That's the main problem.

Comment: @LucasZanella who are you? The widget was made as per specs of OP.

Comment: Also the width of MyWidget can be set

Comment: @bluenile hi sorry I commented with my friend's account. So, when added 2 MyWidget, then should only take their space when not expanded, but they take the entire screen as width. They should take WIDTH_1 when not expanded and WIDTH_2 when expanded

Comment: The width currently is `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,`, that's the problem. I need a width `WIDTH_1`when not expanded and one when expanded `WIDTH_2`

Comment: I've shared the code with you and I think I've answered in entirety as per scope of this question. The question did not mention 2 or 25 widgets. It is OK do not accept the answer, but I will keep my answer to this much. If it interests you start a new question.

Comment: @bluenile sorry for the trouble. I accepted your answer, upvoted and gave you the bounty. I did not explain my problem correctly. I opened another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296595/simple-expandable-column-on-flutter-wont-have-title-expandable-too. I'll open a bounty (after 2 days) to reward 200 points to anyone who solves it. Please take a look, and again, thank you very much for this answer.