# Simple expandable column on Flutter wont have Title > expandable too

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to make an Expandable Column. That is, it has 2 children: the child and the expanded child that appears when the widget is expanded.

In the picture below, you see the child (blue) and expanded child (red) which should only appear when the `Expand >`  button is clicked.

[image]

**Everything is working, but no mater what I do, I cannot get the `Expand >` button to work like this:
`Expand >` when not expanded, and `Expand        (lots of spaces)   <` when expanded.**

This is the code of the Expand button:

```
      Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            //Expanded() would be the solution here, but it breaks cause it's inside ListView
            Container(
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, top: 15),
                child: Text(this.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                        color: Colors.white)),
              )),
            //Expanded() would be the solution here, but it breaks cause it's inside ListView
            Container(
              child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 7, top: 15),
                  child: expanded != null && expanded
                      ? Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
                      color: Colors.grey)
                      : Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                      color: Colors.grey))),
        ])
```

The obvious solution would be to make this `Row` have 2 `Expanded` children instead of 2 `Container`, but if you do that everything brakes because it's inside a `ListView` scrollable horizontally, so it tries to expand forever.

**Entire code in Dartpad:**

https://dartpad.dev/dccfb8c0efa98f5da64eca625ccf1487

If you substitute `Container()` by `Expanded()` as I mentioned, the layout wont render.

I've been thinking for a long time on how to fix this, but the `ExpandableListTitle` can't possibly know the size of its parent since the size of its parent depends on the size of the children: expanded and not expanded.

PS: The `ListView` cannot be changed by a `Row`, I really need to scroll between these expandable widgets horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were passing the function wrong. Please check the code now.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = const Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

const double COLUMN_WIDTH = 150;
const double COLUMN_WIDTH_EXPANDED = COLUMN_WIDTH;
const double COLUMN_WIDTH_TOTAL_EXPANDED = COLUMN_WIDTH + COLUMN_WIDTH_EXPANDED;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                height: 300,
                child: ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: [
                  ExpandableColumn(
                    title: "Expand",
                    child: Container(width: COLUMN_WIDTH, color: Colors.blue),
                    expandedChild: Container(
                        width: COLUMN_WIDTH_EXPANDED, color: Colors.red),
                    expanded: false,
                  ),
                  ExpandableColumn(
                    title: "Expand",
                    child: Container(width: COLUMN_WIDTH, color: Colors.green),
                    expandedChild: Container(
                        width: COLUMN_WIDTH_EXPANDED, color: Colors.purple),
                    expanded: false,
                  ),
                ]))),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExpandableColumn extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpandableColumn(
      {Key key,
      this.title,
      @required this.child,
      this.expandedChild,
      this.onExpand,
      this.expanded})
      : super(key: key);
  final Widget child;
  final Widget expandedChild;
  final Function onExpand;
  final String title;
  final bool expanded;

  @override
  ExpandableColumnState createState() => ExpandableColumnState();
}

class ExpandableColumnState extends State<ExpandableColumn>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool expIcon = false;
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;
  //Animation<double> _animationT;
  Function onExpand;
  bool expanded;
  final Duration duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 200);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    onExpand = widget.onExpand;
    expanded = widget.expanded;
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: duration,
      vsync: this,
    );
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
  }

  updateExpansion() {
    // if (expanded) {
    //   _controller.forward();
    // } else {
    //   _controller.reverse();
    // }
    !expanded
        ? Future.delayed(duration).then((value) {
            expIcon = !expIcon;
            _controller.reverse();
            setState(() {});
          })
        : _controller
            .forward()
            .then((value) => setState(() => expIcon = !expIcon));
  }

  onPressed() {
    expanded = !expanded;
    updateExpansion();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Container(
          child: Column(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
            ExpandableListTitle(
              title: widget.title,
              expanded: expanded,
              onPress: onPressed,
              expIcon: expIcon,
              columnWidth: expanded
                  ? (_animation.value * 150 + 150)
                  : expIcon
                      ? (_animation.value * 150 + 150)
                      : COLUMN_WIDTH,
              duration: duration,
              // onPress: () => {
              //   setState(() {
              //     expanded != null ? expanded = !expanded : expanded = true;
              //     updateExpansion();
              //     if (onExpand != null) onExpand(expanded);
              //   })
              // },
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              child:
                  Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                Container(
                  width: COLUMN_WIDTH,
                  child: widget.child,
                ),
                SizeTransition(
                    sizeFactor: _animation,
                    axis: Axis.horizontal,
                    axisAlignment: -1,
                    child: Container(
                        width: COLUMN_WIDTH, child: widget.expandedChild))
              ]),
            ))
          ])),
    );
  }
}

class ExpandableListTitle extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpandableListTitle({
    Key key,
    this.title,
    this.expanded,
    this.onPress,
    this.expIcon,
    this.columnWidth,
    this.duration,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final bool expanded;
  final Function onPress;
  final bool expIcon;
  final double columnWidth;
  final Duration duration;
  @override
  _ExpandableListTitleState createState() => _ExpandableListTitleState();
}

class _ExpandableListTitleState extends State<ExpandableListTitle>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _alignAnimationEnded = false;
  // bool expanded;
  // Function onPress;
  // String title;
  // @override
  // void initState() {
  //   super.initState();
  //   expanded = widget.expanded;
  //   onPress = widget.onPress;
  //   title = widget.title;
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: widget.columnWidth,
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        // onTap: () =>
        //     onPress != null ? onPress() : print('ExpandableListTitle tap'),
        onTap: () {
          _alignAnimationEnded = false;
          widget.onPress();
        },
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
                child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, top: 15),
              child: Text(this.widget.title,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      color: Colors.white)),
            )),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 7, top: 15),
                child: AnimatedAlign(
                  onEnd: () => setState(() => _alignAnimationEnded = true),
                  duration: widget.duration,
                  alignment: widget.expanded && widget.expIcon
                      ? Alignment.centerRight
                      : Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: widget.expanded
                      ? widget.expIcon && _alignAnimationEnded
                          ? const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
                              color: Colors.grey)
                          : const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                              color: Colors.grey)
                      : widget.expIcon
                          ? const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
                              color: Colors.grey)
                          : const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                              color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. I considered inserting a fixed width to the `ExpandableListTitle` as well, but I got the same behaviour as with your correction. With your correction, as soon as we expand, the `ExpandableListTitle` grows in an instant. This makes the entire widget grows instantly. However, the second column is animated, and it takes time to grow. This makes the second column make a jump. If you make the duration of the animation 4 seconds, we can see the problem beter: http://dartpad.dev/21efb87afaf5e253a56745979ba1c5b9

Comment: Updated the code. Please check if it works for your requirements.

Comment: Updated the code, works exactly like your requirement. Please check

Comment: Also added your updated code working as per your requirements. Please check both the versions of the code and use the one you like better. Thanks,

Comment: I'm going to test soon but it looks like it work. Just give me some hours, thanks

Comment: I took a look. Indeed it works. However, on real Android devices (not on dartpad), I noticed the following: since you're using `AnimatedBuilder` instead of `SizeTransition`, you're squeezing the elements when the expandedChild gets very small, this gives `A RenderFlex overflowed by 4.1 pixels on the right.`. When using `SizeTransition`, nothing is squeezed, since it essentialy hides things instead of squeezing them. Do you know what can be done?

Comment: The first one above or second one?

Comment: Also are you changing the values of child column or expanded column, please give more details of what you are doing.

Comment: Please check now, this is mostly entirely your code now with a few changes to make it work as per your requirements.

Comment: I did not forget, gonna look soon, sorry for the delay

Comment: It seems to work, however the `>` isn't animated. I've thinking on how to animate it, but it'd require to set a size. I think it's ok if it does not animate together with the expansion, only after, but at least it should animate. I'm ready to give you 200 points if you want, but do you have an idea on how to animate it? I'll give extra 50 points

Comment: Updated the code. Now the code even animates the `>` icon. It works exactly as you want. Hope you keep your promise of 250 bounty.

Comment: Just activated the bounty. Have to wait 24 hours to give to you. Thank you so much!